# Mocking multiple Vector<String> with @Spy and @InjectMocks

Tags: spring, junit, dependency-injection, mockito, spy

I am writing a JUnit Test where I need to inject mocks of 2 Vectors as follows:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractMyObject {  
    @Autowired
    private Vector<String> firstVector;

    @Autowired
    private Vector<String> secondVector;

    public abstract void  absFunc();

    public void doThis() {
        System.out.println(firstVector);
        System.out.println(secondVector);
    }
}

@Component
public class MyObject extends AbstractMyObject {
    public MyObject(final Vector<String> firstVector, final Vector<String> secondVector) {
        super(firstVector, secondVector);
    }
    @Override
    public void absFunc() {

    }
}

public class TestClass {
    private static String[] array1 = {"Hello", "World"};
    private static String[] array2 = {"junit", "mockito"};

    @Spy
    private Vector<String> firstVector = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(array1));

    @Spy
    private Vector<String> secondVector = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(array2));

    @InjectMocks
    private MyObject myObject;

    private void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        initMocks();
        myObject.doThis();
    }
}
```

The output of running this test is: [Hello, World]

**How do I make sure that both the vectors are correctly assigned?**

I could not find any examples or documentation about using @Qualifier with Spy and InjectMocks.

Comment: What do you mean by _so that the injection framework does not get confused_?  Is there some specific problem you need to solve.  Please clarify.

Comment: I see that, in the unit test when the Spies are injected they contain the same value which is array2. That is the mock MyObject contains 2 vectors, both initialized to array2.

Comment: Please show the test code in which you are observing this problem.

Comment: I have updated the code with required classes. I see that this happens when the class under question is a derived class from an abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling super() from the base class which is incorrect. Since the members were @Autowire-d there is no need for super().